# tinyxml and yaml-cpp

Tags: ros, rosdep, gumstix, tinyxml, yaml-cpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install opencv packages on a Gumstix Overo COM.  I have successfully installed the base ROS functions such as roscore, rosmake, etc. and I can run roscore with several nodes.  However, some of the opencv packages require tinyxml and yaml-cpp, which rosdep is not able to install on the Gumstix's ARM processor.  Thus, I tried to install the packages from source:

yaml-cpp : http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/downloads/list

tinyxml  : http://code.google.com/p/libtinyxml/

Both programs compile/install natively with: cmake, make, sudo make install.

However, rosdep still can't find the system dependencies for tinyxml and yaml-cpp.

Where does rosdep look for the system dependencies?

Gumstix OS: Ubuntu 10.04
Using ROS Electric

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11614/tinyxml-and-yaml-cpp/) by [SyllogismRXS](https://answers.ros.org/users/715/syllogismrxs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2011-10-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep is a front-end to package managers like apt, pip, macports, yum, etc... It (generally) does not attempt to look for your own source-based installations.  Thus, if you've installed the system dependencies yourself, you don't need to use rosdep, in the same way that you don't need to use apt.

If the dependencies aren't being located, then you'll need to look in:

1. the tinyxml and yamlcpp ROS packages and see if the manifest.xml is correctly forwarding the flags (look for the  export)
2. the CMakeLists.txt build files of the things that are failing to build to see if they are linking improperly

In ROS Electric, we started transitioning both tinyxml and yamlcpp to system dependencies, which is why there are two places to look.  In future releases, it will just be #2.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3